# Статическая линковка C++ рантайма к динамической библиотеке

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, линковка, mingw-w64

Пытаюсь собрать приложение `app`, прилинковав его к динамической библиотеке `library` так, чтобы больше никаких dll для запуска `app.exe` не требовалось (кроме системных и MSVCRT.dll). Использую `MinGW`.

Для этого C++ runtime линкую с опцией `-static`, что на выходе даёт "чистую" `library.dll` (зависящую только от kernel32.dll и MSVCRT.dll судя по dependency walker-у):

```
set(LIB_NAME library)
set(LIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(${LIB_NAME} SHARED)
target_sources(${LIB_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIB_INCLUDE_DIR}/${LIB_NAME}/Some.hpp src/Some.cpp) # Some.hpp и Some.cpp -- сорсы библиотеки
target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB_INCLUDE_DIR})

if (WIN32 AND MINGW)
    target_link_options(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC -static)
endif (WIN32 AND MINGW)
```

Проблемы начинаются при линковке приложения:

```
set(APP_NAME app)
add_executable(${APP_NAME})
target_sources(${APP_NAME} PRIVATE src/main.cpp) # main.cpp - сорс приложения
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIB_NAME})
```

На этапе линковки библиотеки к приложению `ld` выдаёт

> multiple definition of `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'

Судя по всему, это происходит от того, что опция `-static` передается приложению из-за `PUBLIC` спецификатора, и мы получаем 2 одинаковые версии libstd++ и libgcc, встроенные как в библиотеку, так и в приложение (1 функция импортируется из main.cpp, другая из some.cpp).

Если поставить

```
target_link_options(${LIB_NAME} PRIVATE -static)
```

, то ошибок линковки не возникает, но приложение (в отличие от библиотеки) требует динамический рантайм для запуска, что не соответствует цели.

Единственный "рабочий" вариант, который я пока нашёл, линковать библиотеку к приложению следующим образом:

```
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} PRIVATE -Wl,--whole-archive ${LIB_NAME} -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

Однако не до конца понимаю смысл этого флага и правильность решения. Также почему-то dependency walker продолжает показывать зависимоть от .dll, хотя сейчас запуск возможен без неё.

Какое решение правильное?

UPD: после удаления и восстановления папки с CMake-кешем и перезапуска dependency walker-а предложение "почему-то dependency walker продолжает показывать зависимоть от .dll" стало неактуально.

Comment: Вам надо не dll линковать к приложению, а библиотеку `*.a`. Обычно, при сборке dll получается 3 файла: `my.dll`, `my.dll.a` и `my.a`. Библиотека `my.dll.a` обычно небольшого размера и служит для динамической линковки с dll, а вот `my.a` по размеру будет сопоставима с размером dll и служит для статической линковки.

Comment: Я может чего-то не знаю, но каким образом соотносится MinGW с MSVCRT?

Comment: Если используется флаг `-static` при сборке проекта, но в тоже время нужно прилинковать какую-то библиотеку динамически, используйте опцию `-Wl,-Bdynamic -lmy_lib_name`. Или, можно ещё гибче: `gcc program.o -llib1 -Wl,-Bstatic -llib2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -llib3` линкует lib1 и lib3 динамически, а lib2 статически.